# Pointer variable assignment

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I have created a struct:

```
struct time
{
    int hours;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
    double total_time;
    double price;

    time* next;
    time* back;
};
```

I have created 2 pointers to the struct:

```
time* traverse, head;
```

I wanted to point the location of head to the same locations as head:

```
traverse = new time;
    head = traverse; // Error here
```

Why is it that I am getting an error at the assignment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When writing

```
time* traverse, head;
```

the star only affects the first variable. Change your declaration to

```
time *traverse, *head;
```

and the error should be gone.

Answer (score 3):

The declaration of pointer is wrong

```
time* traverse, head;
```

It just declare a pointer and an object

You should declare it as:

```
time* traverse;
time* head;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't declare `head` as a pointer:

```
time* traverse, *head;   //both are pointers
```

is not the same as

```
time* traverse, head;    //one is a pointer, one is an object
```